# Determine if msdb.dbo.backupset record is a backup or a restore

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to identify if a msdb.dbo.backupset record is a backup or a restore?

We are writing an application to archive backups.
To determine if there are new backups we check msdb.dbo.backupset, but this table holds records for both backups and restores.

To filter out restores backupsets we only show records where the backup_set_id does not exist in the restorehistory table.

The problem is, if we backup a database, then it is later restored to the same server, the backup would be seen as a restore and not shown.

I've considered if backupset.servername = @@servername we can assume its a backup.. but that seems fragile.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried a join with msdb.dbo.restorehistory on backup_set_id? Both of those tables should have the same retention, so if it was restored (whether the original backup happened on the same server or not), it should be present there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
    b.backup_set_id, r.backup_set_id, b.backup_finish_date, r.restore_date
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset b
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.restorehistory r
    ON b.backup_set_id = r.backup_set_id
WHERE
    r.restore_date IS NULL -- no restore record.
    OR r.restore_date > b.backup_finish_date; -- restore happened after backup was created.
```

The idea here is that if the [restore_date] is greater than the [backup_finish_date] then we'd still want to include the original backup set in the resultset.

Comment: Not sure why this would work. Wouldn't the restore_date always be greater than the backup_finish_date?